# I don't fully understand sqlite3_finalize

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite

I don't fully understand sqlite3_finalize. My initialy code.

```
while (j < Autors.count)
{
 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
 {
    sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement,  1, ((AuthorSettings *)[Autors objectAtIndex:j]).authorId);
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) 
    {    
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_step error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, 5);
    } 
    else
    {    
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement_1, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement,  1, bookId);
            if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) 
            {    
                NSLog(@"sqlite3_step error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, 5);
            }    
            else  j++;    
        } 
        else NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare_v2 error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }    
 }
}
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
```

I added sqlite3_finalize functions. Please check me.

```
while (j < Autors.count)
 {
 sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); //**added
 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
 {
    sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement,  1, ((AuthorSettings *)[Autors objectAtIndex:j]).authorId);
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) 
    {    
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_step error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, 5);
    } 
    else
    {   
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); //**added
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement_1, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement,  1, bookId);
            if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) 
            {    
                NSLog(@"sqlite3_step error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                sqlite3_busy_timeout(database, 5);
            }    
            else  j++;    
        } 
        else NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare_v2 error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }    
 }
}
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sqlite3_finalize` is the opposite of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. So your code should look something like this:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(...);
while () {
  sqlite3_reset(...);
  sqlite3_bind_int(...);
  sqlite3_step(...);
}
sqlite3_finalize(...);
```

You don't want to prepare you statements more than necessary.

Comment: if you using sqlite3_exec you need use sqlite3_finalize too?

Comment: @ademar111190 As the documentation says, "The sqlite3_finalize() function is called to delete a prepared statement." So if you don't prepare a statement, there is no need to finalise it.

Comment: thanks, seems to be just that, if i call sqlite3_finalize with sqlite3_exec sometimes i get a runtime error.